# How to change the colour of specific text in PHP

Tags: php, html, css, web

I have got some text that I am wanting to change the colour of that i cant seem to fix for the life of me.

The code is:

```
<?php
echo nl2br ("I was born in:  $MEL, $AUS \n" );?>
```

Now I am wanting to just change the colour of the "I was born in" part of the text.

I understand that you cannot directly change the colour of the text as this is PHP and not HTML but is there a way of doing so with the use of a CSS file.

I hope I am being clear with what i require

Many Thanks in advance

Comment: if you use [`<span>`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_span.asp) you can directly change the colour with php

Comment: You can only set the color once with PHP, because it is rendered on the server-side. You could change it on the client's side with JavaScript, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php
echo nl2br ("<span style=\"color:red;\">I was born in:</span>  $MEL, $AUS \n" );
?>
```

Comment: Legend. Works a charm. Thanks you so much!

Comment: @GeordanBombos If this has solved it for you, can you click the checkbox to mark as answered. Thanks!